# hadoop textinputformat read only one line per file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I wrote a simple map task for hadoop 0.20.2, the input dataset consists of 44 files, each is about 3-5MB. Each line of any file has the format `int,int`. The input format is the default `TextInputFormat` and the mapper's work is to parse the input `Text` into the integers.

After the task run, the statistics of hadoop framework shew that the number of input records for map task is just 44. I tried debug and found that the input records for the method `map` are just the first line of each file.

Does anyone know what the problem is and where can I find the solution?

Thank you in advanced.

**Edit 1**

The input data were generated by a different map-reduce task whose output format is `TextOutputFormat<NullWritable, IntXInt>`. The `toString()` method of `IntXInt` should give a string of `int,int`.

**Edit 2**

My mapper looks like the following

```
static class MyMapper extends MapReduceBas
  implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {

  public void map(LongWritable key,
                  Text value,
                  OutputCollector<IntWritable, IntWritable> output,
                  Reporter reporter) {

    String[] s = value.toString().split(",");
    IntXInt x = new IntXInt(s[0], s[1]);
    output.collect(x.firstInt(), x.secondInt());
  }
}
```

**Edit 3**

I have just checked, the mapper actually reads only 1 line for each file, NOT the whole file as one `Text` value.

Comment: Did you have a look at your output?

Comment: @smttsp: The output is 44 records.

Comment: could you provide your reducer too?

Comment: Can you give us a sample head of one of the input files (`hadoop fs -text part-r-00000 | head`)

Answer (score 0):

The InputFormat defines how to read data from a file into the Mapper instances.The default TextInputFormat reads lines of text files. The key it emits for each record is the byte offset of the line read (as a LongWritable), and the value is the contents of the line up to the terminating '\n' character (as a Text object).If you have multi-line records each separated by a $ character, you should write your own InputFormat that parses files into records split on this character instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that your mapper gets all text as input and prints an  output. Could you show your Mapper class decleration and mapper function decleration? i.e

```
static class MyMapper extends Mapper <LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>{ 
    public void map (LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //do your mapping here

    }
}
```

I wonder if there is something different in this line